# Having problems with persisting to database using EJB and JPA

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception, ejb

Here is the entity

```
  package com.ose.bookstore.model.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Login
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Login implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Login() {
        super();
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int loginId;
    private String userEmail;
    private String password;
    private String secPassword;



    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getSecPassword() {
        return secPassword;
    }
    public void setSecPassword(String secPassword) {
        this.secPassword = secPassword;
    }
    public int getLoginId() {
        return loginId;
    }
    public void setLoginId(int loginId) {
        this.loginId = loginId;
    }
}
```

Here is the Controller/Test Class

```
package com.ose.bookstore.model.test;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import com.ose.bookstore.model.ejb.LoginDao;
import com.ose.bookstore.model.entity.Login;

/**
 * @author nishant
 * 
 */
@SessionScoped
public class LoginTest1 {

    @EJB
    private static LoginDao loginDao;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Login login = new Login();
            login.setLoginId(2);
        login.setPassword("asdf");
        login.setSecPassword("asdfsadF");
        login.setUserEmail("email");
        loginDao.writeToDb(login);
    }
}
```

Here is the EJB class

```
package com.ose.bookstore.model.ejb;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.ose.bookstore.model.entity.Login;

/**
 * @author nishant
 *
 */
@Remote
@Stateless
public class LoginDao {

    public LoginDao() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager; 
    public void writeToDb(Login login){
        entityManager.persist(login);
    }

}
```

I am getting this error loginDao.writeToDb(login);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ose.bookstore.model.test.LoginTest1.main
LoginTest1 is the class name of Controller/Test class

Comment: Try to remove the `static` in `@EJB private static LoginDao loginDao;`

Comment: Since the object has to be used in the main class, loginDao has to be static 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field loginDao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the client code inside an [Application client container](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakv.html#beakw). Otherwise the @EJB local injection doesn't work (your test code is executing like a javastandalone but it needs a Container that inject the EJB)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a remote/local interface exposing the business methods.

This interface will be used by the ejb client application.

Use @Local annotation if ejb client is in same environment where ejb session bean is to be deployed.

Use @Remote annotation if ejb client is in different environment where ejb session bean is to be deployed.

```
@Remote
public interface LoginDaoRemote {
   public void writeToDb(Login login);
}

@Stateless
public class LoginDao implements LoginDaoRemote {

@Override
public void writeToDb(Login login){
    entityManager.persist(login);
  }
}
```